# XMPPError: subscription-required - auth

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

Making  Chat App using Smack ,
Try  to  get the Last Seen time of user  but getting following Exception

```
org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: subscription-required - auth
```

Code :

```
  public void getLastSeen(String JID) {


        LastActivityManager mLastActivity = LastActivityManager.getInstanceFor (connection);
        try {
            try {
                mLastActivity.getLastActivity (JID);
                Log.e (TAG, "" + mLastActivity.getLastActivity (JID));


            } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ( );
            }

        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
        }

    }
```

getting above Exception on following line

```
  mLastActivity.getLastActivity (JID);
```

Anybody know why getting this exception ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely because you need to be subscribed to the contact's presence in order to retrieve the last activity.

Comment: How exactly to  subscribe contact's presence in order to retrieve the last activity? Could you provide working clear code sample?

Comment: Hi @Arsenius, please check below answer. It may be useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to setup roster once xmpp connection established :

```
  private fun setupRoaster() {
    if (conn1 == null) {
        Timber.d("setupRoaster failed , due to connection is null $conn1")
    } else {
        conn1?.let {
            roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(conn1)
            roster?.subscriptionMode = Roster.SubscriptionMode.manual
            roster?.addRosterListener(this)
            Timber.d("setupRoaster roster?.entryCount : ${roster?.entryCount}")

            roster?.addSubscribeListener(object:SubscribeListener{
                override fun processSubscribe(
                    from: Jid?,
                    subscribeRequest: Presence?
                ): SubscribeListener.SubscribeAnswer {
                    Timber.d("setupRoaster SubscribeListener calledback Approved")
                     return  SubscribeListener.SubscribeAnswer.Approve
                }

            })

            if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
                //Here we are observed all the roster contacts and status
                roster?.let {
                    for(ros in it.entries){
                        Timber.d("setupRoaster Info isSubscriptionPending ::  ${ros.isSubscriptionPending}  isApproved :: ${ros.isApproved} type :: ${ros.type}  isSubscribedToMyPresence : ${roster?.isSubscribedToMyPresence(ros.jid)} ros.jid : ${ros.jid}")
                        //ros.isSubscriptionPending
                    }
                }
            }



            Timber.d("setupRoaster success")
        }
        Timber.d("setupRoaster failed $conn1")
    }

}
```

To add any user into your roster use below code :

```
override suspend fun addContactToRoster(toUserId: String, name: String) {
    Coroutines.io {
        Timber.d("addContactToRoster 1 $toUserId")
        if(roster == null){
            setupRoaster()
        }
        if (roster != null) {

            Timber.d("addContactToRoster 2 roster?.isLoaded : ${roster?.isLoaded} ")
            try {
                roster?.let {
                    if(it.isLoaded && !it.isSubscribedToMyPresence(getJabberId(toUserId))){
                        val presence = Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe)
                        presence.setTo(getJabberId(toUserId))
                        presence.setType(Presence.Type.subscribed)
                        conn1?.sendStanza(presence)
                        roster?.createEntry(getJabberId(toUserId), name, null)
                    }
                }

                Timber.d("addContactToRoster Contact added to roster successfully")
            } catch (e: SmackException.NotLoggedInException) {
                Timber.d("addContactToRoster SmackException.NotLoggedInException called ${e.message} conn1?.isConnected ${conn1?.isConnected} conn1.isAuthenticated : ${conn1?.isAuthenticated}")
                login()
            } catch (e: SmackException.NoResponseException) {
                Timber.d("addContactToRoster SmackException.NoResponseException called ${e.message} conn1?.isConnected ${conn1?.isConnected} conn1.isAuthenticated : ${conn1?.isAuthenticated}")
            } catch (e: SmackException.NotConnectedException) {
                Timber.d("addContactToRoster SmackException.NotConnectedException called ${e.message} conn1?.isConnected ${conn1?.isConnected} conn1.isAuthenticated : ${conn1?.isAuthenticated}")
            }
        } else {
            Timber.d("addContactToRoster Roster not initilized,")
            Timber.d("addContactToRoster May when user comes first time at that time internet not available so connection not established")
        }
    }

}
```

Once user successfully added to roster and receiver accept your subscription than you can last get activity/last seen by using below method :

```
 fun getLastActivity(userId: String): String? {
    Timber.d("XMPP :: getLastActivity $userId called conn1 : $conn1")
    val jabberId = getJabberId(userId)
    jabberId?.let {
        Timber.d("XMPP :: getLastActivity 1 ${jabberId}")
        conn1?.let {
            Timber.d("XMPP :: getLastActivity 2")
            if (it.isConnected && it.isAuthenticated) {
                Timber.d("XMPP :: getLastActivity 3")
                try {
                    val lastActivityManager: LastActivityManager =
                        LastActivityManager.getInstanceFor(conn1)
                    //val jid : Jid = JidCreate.from("u1304@quantumpigeon.com");
                    val status = lastActivityManager.isLastActivitySupported(jabberId)
                    val lastStatus = lastActivityManager.getLastActivity(jabberId)
                    Timber.d(
                        "XMPP :: lastStatus.toString $lastStatus \n lastStatus.lastActivity ${lastStatus.lastActivity} " +
                                "\n lastStatus.idleTime : ${lastStatus.idleTime} \n lastStatus.message : ${lastStatus.message} \n lastStatus.statusMessage : ${lastStatus.statusMessage}"
                    )
                    val milliSeconds =
                        applicationContext.getTrueTimeNow().time - (lastStatus.lastActivity * 1000)
                    //val lastSeen = getDate(milliSeconds, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS")
                    val lastSeen = getLastSeen(milliSeconds)
                    Timber.d("XMPP :: isLastActivitySupported : $status  lastStatus : $lastStatus LastSeen : $lastSeen")
                    return lastSeen
                } catch (e: XMPPException.XMPPErrorException) {
                    Timber.d("XMPP :: Error in get last activity : ${e.message}")
                } catch (e: SmackException.NoResponseException) {
                    Timber.d("XMPP :: SmackException.NoResponseException. : ${e.message}")
                } catch (e: SmackException.NotConnectedException) {
                    Timber.d("XMPP :: SmackException.NotConnectedException. : ${e.message}")
                }
            } else {
                Timber.d("XMPP :: handleNotConnectedException : ${it.isConnected} or authenticated ${it.isAuthenticated}")
                // handleNotConnectedException()
            }
            Timber.d("XMPP :: Connection not connected : ${it.isConnected} or authenticated ${it.isAuthenticated}")

        }
        Timber.d("XMPP :: Connection not established $conn1")

    }

    return null
}
```